# Dúvidas com Datas menores que 31/12/69 em PHP

Tags: php, data

Galera,

Estou com um problema ao transformar datas do banco de dados para serem apresentadas em tela.

Em meu código faço o seguinte.

```
$objReturn['DADOS'][$key]['DATA_NASCIMENTO'] = date('d/m/y', strtotime($value[DATA_NASCIMENTO]));
```

Porém o que aparece em minha tela é

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ao retornar o valor da seguinte maneira

```
$objReturn['DADOS'][$key]['DATA_NASCIMENTO'] = $value[DATA_NASCIMENTO];
```

O resultado em tela é este

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja no banco, a informação está salva corretamente.

Creio que meu problema esteja na maneira como formato esta data no PHP.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependendo da versão do PHP que utilizar pode fazer assim:

```
$date = date_create($value[DATA_NASCIMENTO]);
$objReturn['DADOS'][$key]['DATA_NASCIMENTO'] = date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
```

Veja se retorna corretamente.

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou sim. Obrigado